# razor: post value is old value (unaltered)

Tags: asp.net, razor

I have a simple form:

```
            <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-page-handler="Button_Submit">
              
                <input value="@Model.yolonese.test" name="hi" />
                <input style="width: 30% !important; opacity: 0.2; " value="Weiter" class="baseButton" type="submit">

            </form>
```

a page model:

```
        public class Skills : PageModel
        {
    
        public Yolonese yolonese { get; set; }
        public Skills()
        {
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
            yolonese = new Yolonese();
        }
        public void OnPost(Yolonese model)
        {
        }
    
    }
```

and a model:

```
public class Yolonese
{
    public string test { get; set; } = "test";
}
```

When my page is rendered, the input value displays "test".
When I alter the value and check for what is posted, "test" is returned. Irregardless of what I wrote into the input.

Why is that?

Comment: You're creating a new instance of Yolonese when Skills is instantiated, and your default values for the property "test" is "test". Don't do that. Where's your controller?

Comment: this is all the files that I have. I understand what you are saying. But if I didnt go "new Yolonese()" then page reload crashes with: not instance of object...

Comment: Actually, even when I create the object in the OnGet() I still be returned the unaltered values...

Comment: @LarryBud I updated the answer the way I am doing it rn, and still the original values are displayed

Comment: When/where is OnGet and OnPost being called? Where's your <form> tag?

Comment: @LarryBud I have upadte the form tag. THe onGet and OnPost are being called upon page load and page post.

Comment: We need your controller code.

Comment: @LarryBud I dont know what else to tell you, these are cshtml page with code behind. SO there is no "controller". You just request the page and the page model and thats it... Can we maybe have a disscussion in chat?

Comment: actually, please see my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is, you cannot bind to an input the way I did, best to use this:

```
 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.test)
```

then the values simply written on the model without the need of an extra controller